# How to control size of prompt dialog box? C#, Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm developing 'Chat Bot' by using MS Framework.

I used 'Prompt.Dialog' to offer a service which users can choose one of few options.

I'd like to modify width of prompt dialog.

However, there are know information of 'Size, Width, Height, etc.'

I attached an image to support my question.
Please help me.

[image]

Comment: And what´s your problem? What have you tried? We´re not doing your work, which is *thinking, trying and searching*.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: I attached an image. You can know what I tried by checking this image.

Comment: @Vivienne no we can't. I don't see anything that you tried.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask in order to determine if you *really* showed what you´ve tried. From my point of view there´s not mucht to see, in particular **no code**, which is what StackOverflow is for. We don´t even know which framework you´re using: WPF? UWP? ASP? ...?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Okay, I was modifying this question. Please check it one more.

Comment: Still unclear what you tried / searched about that, you are just showing the capture of a normal webchat: "I'd like to modify width of prompt dialog." > ok, and what you have tried / searched to do that? You also have to be more precise about your question: do you look for something on the webchat channel? Any channel?

Comment: If you embed Web Chat in a website, you can specify new css style and override the default style.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Fei Han, you can override the default style to adjust the width.  I added a style for wc-card with wc-adaptive-card:

```
<style>
.wc-card.wc-adaptive-card {
      width: 150px;
 }
</style>
```

Results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the width of the prompt dialog in **webchat** even use CSS (It seems well when you use F12 tool to change css, but it will not work when you add css to you html which host the bot). 
But you can change the width of the iframe of the bot, and the width of the prompt dialog will changed automatically.